# JavaFX Gluon android build Failed on Netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans, javafx, gluon

I am new to Gluon plugin. I edited some of the code in build.gradle

```
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'
    applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    resDirectory = 'src/android/res'
    androidSdk ='D:/IT Backup/sdk'
```

and I have D:\IT Backup\sdk\extras\android\support\multidex

but when I build the project to android its failing. giving me this output:

Executing: gradle :android

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

:compileRetrolambdaMain UP-TO-DATE

:processResources UP-TO-DATE

:classes UP-TO-DATE

:compileAndroidJava UP-TO-DATE

:compileRetrolambdaAndroid SKIPPED

:compileEmbeddedJava UP-TO-DATE

:compileRetrolambdaEmbedded SKIPPED

:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE

:compileRetrolambdaTest SKIPPED

:compileRetrolambda UP-TO-DATE

:mergeClassesIntoJar

:validateManifest

:collectMultiDexComponents

:shrinkMultiDexComponents

:createMainDexList

[ant:java] Java Result: 1
:dex FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*** What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dex'.**

using --debug: I got this:

```
13:26:20.763 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :dex FAILED
13:26:20.763 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :dex (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.252 secs.
13:26:20.763 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 6,5,main]] finished, busy: 36.894 secs, idle: 0.015 secs
13:26:20.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:26:20.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
13:26:20.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:26:20.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
13:26:20.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':dex'.
13:26:20.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > org.gradle.api.GradleException (no error message)
13:26:20.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:26:20.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
13:26:20.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
13:26:20.763 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
```

Comment: It is hard to tell if you don't provide more information. If you are running from NetBeans, you can set in the Gradle preferences dialog (Preferences -> Miscellaneous -> Gradle -> Scripts and Tasks) the Gradle argument  `--info`, so when you run the task `android` it will provide more information on the console. Then try again and post any relevant exception you may find.

Comment: well thank you so much. I was wondering how to do that also.

Comment: new error is :dex (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.065 secs.

Comment: Edit your question and post any stacktrace that may be relevant to find out the error.

Comment: i changed the question.

Comment: Your console messages don't show anything relevant. Pleas check again looking for a possible exception or hint to track the error. Also post your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
14:16:14.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Setting project property: dexCmdOut -> Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
14:16:14.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Setting project property: dexCmdErr -> 
14:16:14.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:java] Java Result: 1

Comment: Try to set `-Xmx2000M` under Preferences -> Miscellaneous -> Gradle -> Scripts and Tasks -> Gradle JVM arguments. Is it possible that you are using a 32 bit JDK? Can you use 64 bits?